# How to get key value based on array name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object containing keys in English and values in the Arabic language,

and I want to check if these value == Arabic values
return his key

sample

Object

```
service: {
    Plumber: 'سباكة',
    Electricity: 'الكهرباء',
    Dyeing: 'دهانات',
    Satellite: 'تلفاز ستالايت',
    Cleaning: 'التنظيف',
    Air: 'المكيفات',
  },
```

Arrays

```
['التنظيف','سباكة']
```

so after invoked helper function, i made the result should be this

```
['Plumber','Cleaning'] // in english
```

here's helper function i tried

```
_getKeyByValue = (object, arr) => {
    console.log('engKeys', Object.keys(object)); // eng keys
    let name = arr.map(item => item); // "arr values"
    return Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key] === name);
  };
```

here's how i call

```
 let serv = this._getKeyByValue(englishObject, arrabicArray);
 console.log(serv);
```

but it does not work, it returns undefined

Comment: Are you tranlating between two languages? if  yes change the approach.

Comment: @mehta-rohan Why? I just translate to save eng value in DB! any tips?

Comment: what is the full use case?

Comment: @mehta-rohan I just have a dropDown menu user select service from it "it appears in the Arabic language", after selecting his service it should be saved in a database, so I just want to translate it to English

Comment: why don't you save it like `'سباكة':'Plumber',`

Comment: I don't get what exactly you mean, But I work with firebase DB, and in the user node I save it like [this](https://imgur.com/nUBxap1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code did not work because:

```
let name = arr.map(item => item);
```

returns an array and inside

```
.find(key => object[key] === name);
```

you are trying to compare a string with an array which is always false.

Also, you are using [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method, which only returns the value of the **first** element in the provided array. You need to use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method instead to return all of the matches based on `arrabicArray`.

**WORKING DEMO:**

```js
const englishObject = {
    Plumber: 'سباكة',
    Electricity: 'الكهرباء',
    Dyeing: 'دهانات',
    Satellite: 'تلفاز ستالايت',
    Cleaning: 'التنظيف',
    Air: 'المكيفات',
  };
const arrabicArray = ['التنظيف', 'سباكة'];

const _getKeyByValue = (object, arr) => {
  return Object.keys(object).filter(key => arr.includes(object[key]));
};

let serv = _getKeyByValue(englishObject, arrabicArray);
console.log(serv);
//['Plumber','Cleaning'] // in english
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the object's entries, here is an example:

```js
const service = {
  Plumber: 'سباكة',
  Electricity: 'الكهرباء',
  Dyeing: 'دهانات',
  Satellite: 'تلفاز ستالايت',
  Cleaning: 'التنظيف',
  Air: 'المكيفات',
};

const arr = ['التنظيف', 'سباكة'];

const result = Object.entries(service).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    a.push(key);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

And to deal with duplicates, you can clear the values from `arr` as you find matches:

```js
const service = {
  Plumber: 'سباكة',
  Electricity: 'الكهرباء',
  Dyeing: 'دهانات',
  Satellite: 'تلفاز ستالايت',
  Cleaning: 'التنظيف',
  Air: 'المكيفات',
  Duplicate: 'سباكة',
};

let arr = ['التنظيف', 'سباكة'];

const result = Object.entries(service).reduce((a, [key, value]) => {
  if (arr.includes(value)) {
    arr = arr.filter(v => v !== value);
    a.push(key);
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you @Titus it's work too but palaѕн's Answer it's simple I upvote your answer :)